# How do I replenish grenades?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm running around Mars and Ashley started with 6 grenades, as I've got her grenade tree upgraded significantly.

I had her toss a bunch in the first combat and she was down to 3, and then later on in the mission she was back up to 6. I thought maybe it was from picking up ammo packs, so to test I had her throw one grenade and then I picked up some ammo. She was still at 5 grenades instead of going back up to 6, though. I don't remember specifically seeing any grenades that I picked up, so I'm not sure where they're coming from.

How do I get more grenades?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find grenades lying around, similar to ammo. They're shiny and round and here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Aha! Now that I know what I'm looking for, I saw it literally right in front of where my character was standing when I alt-tabbed out to post this. I'll add a screenshot to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for compensating for my posting answers from my phone at work!